# ListView addHeaderView causes position to increase by one?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

Below is a code snippet with a ListView. I added an emptyView and a headerView. Adding the headerView causes the position in the onItemClick to be increased by one.

So without the headerView the first list element would have position 0, with the headerView the position of the first list element would be 1!

This causes errors in my adapter, e.g. when calling getItem() and using some other methods, see below.
Strange thing: In the getView() method of the adapter the first list element is requested with position 0 even if the headerView is added!!

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView list = (ListView) viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.list);
    View emptyView = viewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.empty);
    list.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    View sectionHeading = inflater.inflate(R.layout.heading, list, false);
    TextView sectionHeadingTextView = (TextView) sectionHeading.findViewById(R.id.headingText);
    sectionHeadingTextView.setText(headerText);
    list.addHeaderView(sectionHeading);

    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listAdapter.getItem(position);
            //Do something with it
        }
    });
}
```

Some adapter methods:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position < items.size()) ? ITEM_NORMAL : ITEM_ADVANCED;
}

    @Override
public Product getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return (position < items.size());
}
```

Is this the normal behaviour when adding a headerView?? And how to overcome the issues in my adapter?

Comment: Your question had the answer to my question. +1

Answer (score 113, accepted):

I just came across this problem and the best way seems to use the `ListView.getItemAtPosition(position)` instead of `ListAdapter.getItem(position)` as the `ListView` version accounts for the headers, ie:-

Do this instead:

```
myListView.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

Comment: So right! `onItemClick` gives you a `parent` for a reason. You can use `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: This didnt actually work for me whereas using @whuandroid decorated / wrapper adapter solution does.

Comment: also you have to cast the item in this case.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even if I cast parent to ListView. I just need to rule out position == 0...

Comment: Does not work for me. `AdapterView` also just passes down to the listAdapter added. `return (adapter == null || position < 0) ? null : adapter.getItem(position);`

Comment: It works. I was facing weird issue where inside 'onListItemClick' method, when I am trying to get data adapter using 'getAdapter' method, it was returning me 'Header' view rather then the adapter which i used with 'setAdapter'. With this solution, no need to get the adapter and one can directly use the parent view (listview). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 32):

If you don't care about the click to the header, subtract the number of header views from the position to get the position for your adapter:

```
        listView.addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.my_hdr_layout, null), null, false);
        listView.setAdapter(m_adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            position -= listView.getHeaderViewsCount();
            final MyObject object = m_adapter.getItem(position);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This should be the best answer, I am not care about the header, I care the listitem.

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work for latest OS 7.0

Answer (score 27):

If you add a header to a `ListView` that becomes the first item in the list. You could compensate for this by overriding the `getCount()` to return one item less, but ensure you handle the `getItem()`, `getItemId()` and so on as the header would be the item in position 0.

Comment: Overriding the getCount() to return one item less doesn't work, because then i miss the last list item of the list. If there is only 1 item in the list then getView() is never called.

Furthermore the adapter is decoupled from the listview and doesn't know if there was a header added to the listview or not.

Comment: In the ListItemClick set position = position - 1 if there is a header attached, I think thats what I did when I faced this particular issue, its not very neat, but the only way I can think of

Comment: I guess the easiest way would be to set position = position-(number of added headerviews) in the OnItemClickListener as you suggested.

I changed my adapter to handle the headerview itself, thus i dont't have to call addHeaderView on the listview. Although the adapter got a bit more complex.

Comment: The "number of added headerviews" can be obtained with: `ListView.getHeaderViewsCount()`

Comment: I don't see how this is the right answer. @Ian Warwick posted the right one, however little bit late I assume.

Comment: Despite the fact that this is checked as "answer", it is actually user1705590 that has it right.  Do *NOT* use the adapter that you pass to the list.  Instead, ask the list for its adapter.  If you use the adapter that you get from myListView.getAdapter, the position will be correct, ignoring both headers and footers.

Comment: Downvoted because unnecessarily complicated. Ian's answer is better. Also see John's comment above

Answer (score 14):

When implementing `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` we just subtract the headers from the position.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    position -= mListView.getHeaderViewsCount();
    // what ever else follows...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

No need to change any code. Simply use below code.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
         //Do something with it
     }
});
```

Comment: This will usually need casting , as the item being returned is just "Object".

Answer (score 9):

Do not use your adapter, use 'decorated' adapter from getAdapter.

Comment: +1 this IMO is the way to go - the adapter you supply is wrapped with another adapter that takes the index offset into account when you supply a header. This code for this is using this is given by @Ramesh elsewhere on this page (+1 to you too!)

Answer (score 5):

One solution to this is to map the id to index. Basically make id return the index in the list and the the click listener would do:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listAdapter.getItem((int) id);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi we can resolve this in this way 
first you create your header view, after inject in your list and the last step unable the setOnClickListener. its works for me. any feedback welcome

```
ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_header, list,false);
list.addHeaderView(headerView);
headerView.setEnabled(false);
headerView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: It's way down the list of answers, but this is really useful. If you don't make these changes, then your header view will remain clickable, with ripple effects etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not to add much new that @Ramesh didn't add but some extra context:

```
personList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long duration) {
        Map<String, Object> person = (Map<String, Object>) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (person != null){

            // If the header was clicked on a null  is returned

            OnPersonUiChangeListener listener = (OnPersonUiChangeListener) getActivity();
            listener.onSelectedPersonChanged(person);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use getSelectedItemPosition() Return the position of the currently selected item within the adapter's data set.
This method don't need to worry about the size of headers or footers.

Answer (score 0):

This might help somebody, improving on Farid_z and Philipp's answer, we can correctly apply the setItemChecked and setTitle with something like this

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        position += 1;
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        position -= 1;
        setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```