# addHeaderView in PreferenceActivity causes position shift

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

My question is like this
[ListView addHeaderView causes position to increase by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106397/listview-addheaderview-causes-position-to-increase-by-one)

Adding addHeaderView to PreferenceActivity causes the position of taps increased by one. So first checkbox never will check, but causes checking of next checkbox and so on.

**This happens only in Android 2.3.6** (tested 2 phones), but never on Android 4.0-4.1.

I read answers the link above but don't know how to apply it to usual native PreferenceActivity. Please give an example for newbie. If possible - without rewriting the native mechanism of Preferences.

here is part of my code

```
public class pref extends PreferenceActivity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "00000");
        ListView v = getListView();
        v.addHeaderView(adView);
...
```

Comment: Did you find an solution for this issue?

Comment: not. Just not use it in old android (checking SDK)