# I get a header layout in adapter's getview() after call addHeaderView()

Tags: android, listview

I want to konw why the following code not work well.

```
  @Override
public void onUpdateView(View view, int position, NewsItemNormal data) {
    ImageView image = ViewUtils.findView(view, R.id.newslist_normal_image);
    TextView titleText = ViewUtils.findView(view, R.id.newslist_normal_title_text);
    TextView timeText = ViewUtils.findView(view, R.id.newslist_normal_time_text);
}
```

onUpdateView() is a method from getview(), called after the getView() get the convertView.My listview has two headerviews and listview items, one of the headerview is viewpager.When i update the data source, this onUpdateView's image & titleText & timeText return null. Debuged and found the onUpdateView reveived '**view**' post from getView() is the headerviews not the item's view.I don't know why, and i worked for android 2 years, i known how to use a adapter with listview.Any help would be great.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follows codes work well.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (null == convertView || !(convertView.getTag(R.id.tag_holder_default) instanceof ViewHolder)) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(R.id.tag_holder_default, holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.id.tag_holder_default);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Pay attention to `(convertView.getTag(R.id.tag_holder_default) instanceof ViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a header view to a ListView, it actually wraps your adapter with a new adapter which contains the header view as the first item. You need to take this into accouut when you deal with the `position` passed in the `getView` method.

For more detail, this post might be helpful.

- [ListView addHeaderView causes position to increase by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106397/listview-addheaderview-causes-position-to-increase-by-one)

Comment: Yes, i notice this HeaderListviewAdapter. It's return three type of view contains header, ours and footer. As we known, the listview cached first screen items's views. And in the next screen, items reused, the header is also. So i have to received the header in my getview().Luckly, the quesstion is solved, i will post the code next.Thanks again.