# listview position getting wrong with section headers

Tags: android, listview, header, listviewitem

I am displaying phone contacts with section headers
but after adding section headers i am getting my position wrong
Here is my code

mycode

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AlphabetListAdapter adapter = new AlphabetListAdapter();
    private List<Object[]> alphabet = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
    private HashMap<String, Integer> sections = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private List<ContactBean> list = new ArrayList<ContactBean>();
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_alphabet);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {

            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            ContactBean objContact = new ContactBean();
            objContact.setName(name);
            objContact.setPhoneNo(phoneNumber);
            list.add(objContact);

        }
        phones.close();


        Collections.sort(list, ContactBean.StuNameComparator);

        List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;
        String previousLetter = null;
        Object[] tmpIndexItem = null;
        Pattern numberPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");

        // for (String country : list) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.size() - 1; i++) {

            String contactName= list.get(i).getName();
            String firstLetter = contactName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

            // Group numbers together in the scroller
            if (numberPattern.matcher(firstLetter).matches()) {
                firstLetter = "#";
            }

            // If we've changed to a new letter, add the previous letter to the
            // alphabet scroller
            if (previousLetter != null && !firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
                end = rows.size() - 1;
                tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
                tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.UK);
                tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
                tmpIndexItem[2] = end;
                alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);

                start = end + 1;
            }

            // Check if we need to add a header row
            if (!firstLetter.equals(previousLetter)) {
                rows.add(new Section(firstLetter));
                sections.put(firstLetter, start);
            }

            // Add the contactNameto the list
            rows.add(new Item(contactName));
            previousLetter = firstLetter;
        }

        if (previousLetter != null) {
            // Save the last letter
            tmpIndexItem = new Object[3];
            tmpIndexItem[0] = previousLetter.toUpperCase(Locale.UK);
            tmpIndexItem[1] = start;
            tmpIndexItem[2] = rows.size() - 1;
            alphabet.add(tmpIndexItem);
        }

        adapter.setRows(rows);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//facing problem here


                Log.v("position", "position-->" + list.get(position).getName());

            }
        });

    }

}
```

**ContactBean.java**

```
public class ContactBean {
    private String name;
    private String phoneNo;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
    /*Comparator for sorting the list by Student Name*/
    public static Comparator<ContactBean> StuNameComparator = new Comparator<ContactBean>() {


    @Override
    public int compare(ContactBean lhs, ContactBean rhs) {
        String contactName1 = lhs.getName().toUpperCase();
           String contactName2 = rhs.getName().toUpperCase();

           //ascending order
           return contactName1.compareTo(contactName2);

    }};


}
```

**AlphabetListAdapter.java**

```
public class AlphabetListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static abstract class Row {
    }

    public static final class Section extends Row {
        public final String text;

        public Section(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    public static final class Item extends Row {
        public final String text;

        public Item(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    private List<Row> rows;

    public void setRows(List<Row> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Row getItem(int position) {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position) instanceof Section) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) { // Item
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            }

            Item item = (Item) getItem(position);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(item.text);
        } else { // Section
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_section, parent, false);
            }

            Section section = (Section) getItem(position);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView.setText(section.text);
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

I am stuck here

Comment: Please avoid putting thanks annotation from your question. [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)

Comment: Solution: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    
    Item item = (Item) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
      
    if (item != null) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

   }
  });

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just look at below example, It's nicely describe how to implement Sectioned Headers in List Views.

1)https://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/

2)http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/

3)https://github.com/beworker/pinned-section-listview

4)http://codetheory.in/android-dividing-listview-sections-group-headers/

Comment: i am implemented correctly as per u r sample but how to get position in listitem click

Comment: check this  link it will be definitely helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106397/listview-addheaderview-causes-position-to-increase-by-one

Comment: You can implement `OnItemClickListener` on a `ListView` to get the position of your row

Comment: pinned-section-listview sample helped me. Thanq Jignesh

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    
    Item item = (Item) listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
      
    if (item != null) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

   }
  });

Comment: @NareshRavva  You can add an answer with the specific code that solved your issue, and accept your own answer.  Link only answers are discouraged:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer